# What is the expected number of rolls in a craps game GIVEN that the player wins?

Tags: probability

I'm currently trying to find the expected number of rolls in a craps game given that the player wins. In a craps game, two fair 6 sided die are rolled. The sum of both is then calculated. If the sum is $2, 3$ or $12$, then the house wins. If the sum is $7$ or $11$, the player wins. If another number $m$ is rolled, ie, not $2, 3, 7, 11$ or $12$, then the die are rolled again and again until $7$ or $m$ comes up. At this point, if $7$ comes up, then the house wins, "craps out". If $m$ comes up, then the player wins.

I am trying to find the expected number of rolls given that the player wins. The way I set it up is:

$$
\text{E(number of rolls given player wins)} = 1\cdot P(7 \ \text{or} \ 11)+2\cdot P(2,3,12,7,11 \  \text{dont come up}) \cdot P(m) + 3 \cdot P(2,3,12,7,11 \  \text{dont come up})\cdot P(7 \ \text{or} \ m \ \text{dont come up}) \cdot P(m) + 4 \cdot P(2,3,12,7,11 \  \text{dont come up})\cdot P(7 \ \text{or} \ m \ \text{dont come up})^2 \cdot P(m) + 5 \cdot P(2,3,12,7,11 \  \text{dont come up})\cdot P(7 \ \text{or} \ m \ \text{dont come up})^3 \cdot P(m) + \cdots
$$

However, what is giving me trouble is probabilities involving $m$, since each $m$ has a different distribution. Is there an easy way to compute the above and am I on the right track? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the right approach.  To handle the different distributions with different $m$'s, break it up:

$$E(\mbox{number of rolls given player wins}) = \sum P_0(\mbox{player wins on m})  E(\mbox{number of rolls given player wins on an m})$$

Here the summation is over $4 \le m \le 11$ - all the values that the player can win on.

$E(\mbox{number of rolls given player wins on an m})$ is calculated for $m \ne 7,11$ by the formula you wrote in your post, excluding the $1 \cdot P(\mbox{7 or 11})$ term; for $m=7,11$, it's trivial.

$P_0(\mbox{player wins on m}) = \frac{P(\mbox{player wins on m})}{P(\mbox{player wins})}$ is the *normalized* probability that the player wins on $m$, given that he won.  So you'll have do to some additional calculations for what is the probability of the player winning for each $m$, and also the overall probability of the player winning.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your post! Didn't think of breaking it up like that, thats genius! I was wondering if the original formula I had still can be computed or if it is non-computable. thanks!

Comment: It can be computed.  Once you specify a value of $m$, then all probabilities in your formula are easily computed, and the infinite series is a geometric series or similar.  But then you need to weight them appropriately to get the final answer, as I have indicated.

Comment: Just one final question, when you write out the normalized probability, $P_0$(player wins on m), is that the same as what I wrote above as $P(m)$, or is what I have above on $P(m)$ equal to P(player wins on m) instead? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Neither.  Your P(m) is the probability that a single roll of the dice produces a total of m.  It is nothing specific to craps.  When I write P(player wins on m), I mean the probability that in a game of craps, the player wins AND the final roll was m.